# How to use sql rank function for different variable

Tags: sql, sql-server, loops

I need to show top 10 num for each countrycode, citycode and age, I confuse how can i use rank function?
i tried with cursor by creating 3 loop for country, city and age but the performance was too bad.
this this how i need to get result ([Original Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NSuJR.jpg)):

```
+ ----------- + -------- + --- + --- +
| CountryCode | CityCode | Age | Num |
+ ----------- + -------- + --- + --- +
| 1           | 2        | 23  | 67  |
| 1           | 2        | 24  | 56  |
| 1           | 2        | 25  | 44  |
| 1           | 6        | 23  | 89  |
| 1           | 6        | 24  | 77  |
| 1           | 7        | 23  | 90  |
| 1           | 2        | 23  | 67  |
| 1           | 2        | 24  | 56  |
| 1           | 2        | 25  | 44  |
| 1           | 6        | 23  | 89  |
| 1           | 6        | 24  | 77  |
| 1           | 7        | 23  | 90  |
+ ----------- + -------- + --- + --- +
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get top 10 nums per combination of countrycode, citycode and age, you can use `dense_rank()`

```
select *
from (
    select t.*,
        dense_rank() over (
            partition by countrycode,
            citycode,
            age order by num desc
            ) seqnum
    from your_table t
    ) t
where seqnum <= 10;
```

Comment: Or replace row_number() with rank(), which will give the same value to ties.

Comment: @MaxSzczurek - `dense_rank` is better suited I think

Comment: yes, maybe dense_rank. To clarify, if there is a tie, dense_rank() will not skip value, but rank() will. For instance, if the ranked num values are 70, 75, 75, 80, dense_rank will rank them as 1,2,2,3, but rank will rank then 1,2,2,4, skipping 3 because there was a tie for #2.

Answer (score 0):

Just to demonstrate how row_number, rank, and dense_rank differ in this context:

```
declare @tbl table 
(
countrycode int, citycode int, age int, num int
)

insert into @tbl
select 1, 7, 23, 70 union all 
select 1, 7, 23, 75 union all 
select 1, 7, 23, 75 union all 
select 1, 7, 23, 80

select *, 
ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by countrycode, citycode, age order by num) as row_number,
RANK() over (partition by countrycode, citycode, age order by num) as rank,
DENSE_RANK() over (partition by countrycode, citycode, age order by num) as dense_rank
from @tbl

+-------------+----------+-----+-----+------------+------+------------+
| countrycode | citycode | age | num | row_number | rank | dense_rank |
+-------------+----------+-----+-----+------------+------+------------+
|           1 |        7 |  23 |  70 |          1 |    1 |          1 |
|           1 |        7 |  23 |  75 |          2 |    2 |          2 |
|           1 |        7 |  23 |  75 |          3 |    2 |          2 |
|           1 |        7 |  23 |  80 |          4 |    4 |          3 |
+-------------+----------+-----+-----+------------+------+------------+
```